# Network-manager openconnect does not change my public ip address

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, cisco, openconnect

I just tried to connect to Cisco any-connect VPN through network-manager or command line.
When I use `sudo openconnect <server_address>` command in command-line I see my public IP address has been changed to VPN server address.
But with network-manager (by creating an open-connect/Cisco VPN connection through the wizard) my public IP address won't change after connecting to VPN.
Why this is happening? Doesn't the second way tunnel my traffic through VPN?

By the way I'm running a Linux lite 5.2 (Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: Did you find a solution? Seems like I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No, I still have this problem

Comment: I've found a partial solution. Checked "Use this connection only for resources on this network" for IP4 and IP6 in the vpn settings. Now when connecting to vpn resources it uses vpn IP. That's how I use company VPN anyway, so it works for me.